# How to refresh the comments with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I was to use ajax to automatically update the page so when a new comment is added I don't have to refresh the page to see it. I have a commented out section in my code where I have tried to do this. I can add posts new comments but when I do I have to refresh the page in order to see the new comment and I just want it to appear automatically when posted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var comments = document.getElementById("allcomments").value; 

     //Get Storage 
                var username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");

        // Call Ajax for existing comments
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'URL.php',
        success: function(result) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(result);

            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var obj = arr[i];   

                var output = document.getElementById("allcomments");  

                output.innerHTML += '<div class="comment-container"><div class="username">'+obj.username+'</div><div class="comment">'+obj.comment+'</div><div class="date">'+obj.commDate+'</div><div class="like">'+obj.sentiment+'</div></div>';

            }

        }
    });

    return false;
}); 

/*//Refresh comments
 var int=self.setInterval("showComments()",5000);

    function showComments(){
        $.post("comments.php", function ( arr ) {
            $("#allcomments").html( arr );
        });
    } */
```

HTML

```
            <h1>Forum</h1>
                <form id="forumPost" method='POST'>
                   <textarea rows="3" col="60" name="comment" placeholder="Create a Post..." id="comment"></textarea>
                   <button><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post' class="post"></button>
                </form>
                <p id="error" class="errormessage"></p>
                <p id="allcomments" class="postmessage"></p>

                <div class="comment-container">
                    <div class="username"><!--obj.username--></div>
                    <div class="comment"><!--obj.comment--></div>
                    <div class="date"><!--obj.commDate--></div>
                    <div class="like"><!--obj.sentiment--></div>
                </div>
```

PHP

```
// Print out existing comment
$query  = "SELECT comments.commDate, comments.ID, comments.username, comments.comment, users.username, comments.sentiment FROM comments LEFT JOIN users ON comments.username = users.username"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if (!$result)
    die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $comments[] = $row; 
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

require_once("db_close.php");

echo json_encode($comments);
```

Comment: Your ajax only executes when the document is ready, which occurs when you refresh the page. You need to determine what event you wish to do your ajax call in reaction to and assign an event to that action to make the ajax call.

Comment: @lurker Would you be able to show me what you mean?

Comment: Gustone has posted an answer describing basically what I meant. The code inside the block `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` is executed when the "document is ready" (after your page is loaded or refreshed, basically). That's why your current code only updates when you refresh the page. You need to write an event handler for a button click or something else that will execute the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your code from this block-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

}
```

Then change

```
<button><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post' class="post"></button>
```

to:

```
<button><input type='button' id='submit' value='Post' class="post"></button>
```

And now put your ajax post code in this block:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){

});
```